Future continuous for complete actions
This is a very reliable grammar book, from CAMBRIDGE. But I don't understand what the author means.

I don't understand the yellow highlight words.
Why is "complete actions"?
"When we use it in this way"=> which/what way?

When we use will be (doing) to talk about an action in the future!

other forms like "be going to" or " will" or "be Ving" also talk about an action in the future.

The action will be done/completed at some point in the future

Yes, they do - so what? This particular paragraph is about will be -ing.

I don't think you ever need to use that particular "future continuous" verb form. It's perfectly okay to say The government are making a statement later today or The government will make a statement later today, and I can't think of any context where any of those three might mean something different to the others. So I suggest learners should stick to my final alternative, which hopefully they'll find more logical - hence easier to understand, remember, and reproduce.

I also don't see how completed action relates to the cited usage. The government will be taxing state pensioners next year is a perfectly acceptable utterance in exactly the same format, but there's no implication that the pensioners will only be subject to a "one-off windfall tax" - in fact, by default one would assume the government would be taxing state pensioners forever once they started, so the action would never "complete".

In light of my previous comment I'm not convinced We also use will be -ing to talk about complete actions in the future is a valid assertion from a trustworthy source. I found it in englishschooloflondon, a site which I suspect has few if any native Anglophones on the payroll. Their "byline" is ESOL - Empowering Confidence, Embracing Diversity. Since I don't think it's possible to "empower confidence", I think the site is worthless.

@FumbleFingers Of course, reputable sources are often plagiarized by disreputable ones. IMO the passage makes a valid point that among the ways we might discuss time-bound future events, and among the uses of future continuous, we might find this. Especially if we see this snippet as explanatory rather than proscriptive.

@FumbleFingers   The grammar book, English Grammar in Use, is written by Raymond Murphy, who is utterly British. I have a copy of it at home. You can find the snippet in Unit 24 Will be doing and will have done

@FumbleFingers Please stop it. Questions like: What will you be doing this summer? are extremely common in English. It is often used to refer to future activities...which have an active component. What will you be playing at the concert tomorrow night? Just because the author did not chose the best word does not mean the examples are bad. Since we actually do say commonly: The org. is making a statement today. It makes sense to say: Will be making for the future  in these cases.

The future continuous has no aspect of completion.

Somebody upvote my previous comment please. The English Grammar in Use claims to be the world's best selling grammar book  It was not written by a non-native Anglophone (I dislike how FF makes that sound like an insult) but by a British author and English language teacher. In case you want further proof read the largely positive reviews

Try looking at the future continuous in terms of the present continuous.
What that Cambridge grammar means:
The government is making a statement today.
COMPARE:
The government will be making a statement tomorrow.
It's complete actions, not completed actions.

Now, I am talking to the Minister of Education.

COMPARE:

Later, I will be talking to the Minister of Education.

The author chose to call that a complete action. Something definite in the future. Probably not the best choice of word. However, the use shows a higher level of activity. Rather than the more dull: The government will make a statement later.
"When we use it [future continuous] in this way, will be (doing) is similar to will (do) and going to (do)."  going to do is more definite as a usual future form. "will" is just will. Often, intention to do something in the future.
it= will be doing.
will be [action verb] is just that. In the future, there will be an action that is describing something that in the present would be present continuous.
Conversation:
Mark: Hey John, so what will you be doing during the summer holidays?
John: Oh man, I'll be surfing for sure.
Why does Mark use the future continuous?
Mark: Hey John, what will you do this summer?
John: Oh man, I'll be surfing.
I'll be surfing is much more active (more physical) than: I will surf.
COMPARE:
Mark: Hey John, what will you do when they find out you stole the surfboard?
John: I won't do anything. After all, it was really mine.
There will means intend in the future. What do you intend to do about it?
Mark: Hey John, what are you going to do this summer?
John: I'm not going to do anything. Just sit around and relax.
That last one is just a straightforward future.

"Complete" doesn't mean "scheduled". The tense signals intention, conviction, plan to be doing something, but "complete" is the wrong word to use for those ideas.

@TimR Yes, I said that complete was not the right word. Perhaps you missed it?

No, I didn't miss your tepid remark that it was "probably not the best choice". It was a very poor choice and the source of the OP's confusion.

@TimR What matters is my explanation and not the word complete.

"Something definite in the future  ... intention to do something in the future"

Note the word "also." I'm not sure whether the context was "We use [some other forms] to talk about complete actions in the future," like maybe simple future tense, or "We use future continuous [for other situations]," like maybe for future actions that will be ongoing for indeterminate amounts of time. Like "I will be attending Cambridge next year."
Either way, the point is: We also use other forms for this purpose, and we also use this form for other purposes. But to explain this particular usage, future continuous can be used for things in the future that will start and finish at a definite time, just as we use simple future, not just for things that will be ongoing or that are unclear about their time span.
But I would echo FumbleFingers advice: I would see this page as explaining a usage that you might encounter, not advising you that you need to use the continuous this way. It's not wrong to do so, but it's confusing, and there's nothing wrong with sticking to simple future for now.
